# jQuery resize function for nav not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I'm using the bootstrap framework and I have a problem with my navigation.

Basically my nav has two different ways of the navigation working. The 'desktop' way and the 'mobile' way.

On the 'desktop' version when the user clicks on a nav link the submenu will appear over the entire screen. This is working correctly as it should.

The 'mobile' version is your standard mobile nav I suppose, only my jQuery looks for any parents then adds a + button next to it. When the user clicks the '+' the children will toggle down and show. This is working correctly too.

The problem comes when I try to resize the window and get them both working if the user was for some reason to switch from the 'desktop' to 'mobile' nav (I suppose checking out the responsiveness).

This is my jQuery:

```
$(".subnav").hide();

    $('.nav-collapse li').each(function(){
        var hasKids = $(this).find('ul').length > 0;
        if(hasKids){
            $(this).children('a')
            .append('<button>+</button>');                     
        }
    });

    function whatnav() {
        if ($(window).width() < 767) {
            $('.nav-collapse li').on('click', 'button', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var plusOrMinus = $.trim($(this).text());

                if(plusOrMinus == '+'){
                    $(this).text('-');
                } else {
                    $(this).text('+');
                }

                $(this).parents('li').find('.subnav').toggle(250);
            });             
        } else {
            $("nav a").click(function () {
                $(this).parent('li').find(".subnav").css("display","table").fadeIn(250);
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
            $(".subnav").click(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(250);
            });         

        }
    }

    $(document).ready(whatnav);
    $(window).resize(whatnav);
```

I created the function 'whatnav' and then made an IF statment - if the window is below 767px then use the 'mobile' nav otherwise use the 'desktop' nav jquery.

If I start in 'mobile' mode and then move to desktop it all works correctly. However if I then change back to the 'mobile' window width it still uses the 'desktop' jQuery snippet rather than the mobile one.

I've never used IF statements before - am I doing it wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Store the initial size of the window as follows:

```
    var initialSize = $( window ).width();
    $( "body" ).data( "viewportSize", initialSize );
```

Then you can perform your check with `$( window ).width()`. Don't forget to update the stored value.

Comment: Hi Gabriele, thank you for replying!

I'm still learning jQuery so forgive my ignorance on this(!) but would it be like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/vYWuU/

I put:

if (initialSize < 767) {
} else {
}

Is that the correct way of doing it? How would I update the stored value?

Many thanks

Comment: I've tried lots of variations, and read the jquery website for the data attribute but I'm not really sure how to update the stored value still - are there any examples anywhere I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time you resize your window, you call `whatnav` which binds the click event handlers over and over again.

Now, if you load it in a mobile sized window, it binds the mobile event handlers. But if you resize to desktop size, it still has the old handlers attached to the elements, and attaches the desktop ones on top. Same thing if you go from desktop size to mobile size.

The code I provided is not ideal, there is a much cleaner way to address your situation, but it's good enough to show how binding and unbinding events is done in jquery :-)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // don't manipulate any element before document is ready!
    $(".subnav").hide();

    $('.nav-collapse li').each(function(){
        var hasKids = $(this).find('ul').length > 0;
        if(hasKids){
            $(this).children('a')
            .append('<button>+</button>');                     
        }
    });
});


function desktopLinkClick(ev) {
    // `ev` is the event object
    // `stopPropagation` prevents the click to be triggered on parent elements
    // you may want to use `preventDefault`, which cancels the click
    ev.stopPropagation();

    $(this).parent('li').find(".subnav").css("display","table").fadeIn(250);
}

function desktopSubnavClick() {
    $(this).fadeOut(250);
}

function mobileButtonClick(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var plusOrMinus = $.trim($(this).text());

    if(plusOrMinus == '+'){
        $(this).text('-');
    } else {
        $(this).text('+');
    }

    $(this).parents('li').find('.subnav').toggle(250);
}

function rebindClickEvents() {
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        // remove previous event handlers
        $("nav a").off('click', desktopLinkClick);
        $(".subnav").off('click', desktopSubnavClick);

        // bind new event handlers
        $('.nav-collapse li button').on('click', mobileButtonClick);
    } else {
        // remove previous event handlers
        $('.nav-collapse li button').off('click', mobileButtonClick);

        // bind new event handlers
        $("nav a").on('click', desktopLinkClick);
        $(".subnav").on('click', desktopSubnavClick);
    }
}

$(document).ready(rebindClickEvents);
$(window).resize(rebindClickEvents);
```